# Extracting unique rows from many dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create multiple filtered dataframe with only unique values.

**Dataset 1**

```
Account     Verified     Paid   Col1 Col2 Col3
1234        True        True     ...  ...  ...
1237        False       True    
1234        True        True
4211        True        True
1237        False       True
312         False       False
```

**Dataset 2**

```
Account          Verified   Paid   Col1 Col2 Col3
41                True      True    ... ... ...
314               False     False
41                True      True
65                False     False
```

Multiple dataframes are called as `dtf[i]` where `i` goes from 1 to 2.
Expected output would be:

**Filtered 1**

```
Account     Verified     Paid
1234        True        False
1237        False       True
4211        True        True

312         False       False
```

**Filtered 2**

```
Account          Verified   Paid
41                True      True
314               False     False
65                False     False
```

How could I extract these unique values?

Comment: `df.groupby(list(df.columns)).agg('first').reset_index()`

Comment: so for each dataset should I run something like: `for x in range(0,1): dtf[x].groupby(list(dtf[x].columns)).agg('first').reset_index()` is it correct?

Comment: thank you to all for the answers. How could I create new dataframes with only filtered rows? I would like to not overwrite the existing dataframe

Comment: `new_dtf = []
for x in range(0,1): 
    new_dtf.append(dtf[x].groupby(list(dtf[x].columns)).agg('first').reset_index())`

Comment: @TomRon, I opened a new question about similar issue. Since your code works fine and I used it for my problem, if you could have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856705/save-duplicates-rows-in-multiple-dataframes/61856886#61856886 it would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to remove the duplicates use the below code, `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','B','A','B','C'], 'col_2':[3,4,3,5,6], 'col_3':[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]})
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates(['col_1','col_2'], inplace = True)
print(df)
```

If you want to pass all the columns to define the uniqueness use `df.columns` instead

```
df.drop_duplicates(df.columns, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

**Edited:**

To pass through all DataFrames in your list, and don't want to replace your df, use the below code and say `inplace = False` (Default)

```
lst_df = [pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','B','A','B','C'], 'col_2':[3,4,3,5,6], 'col_3':[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]}), pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','B','A','B','C'], 'col_2':[3,4,3,5,6], 'col_3':[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]})]
new_lst_df = []
[new_lst_df.append(lst_df[i].drop_duplicates(['col_1', 'col_2'])) for i in range(len(lst_df))]
print(new_lst_df)
```

Comment: How could I create new dataframes with only filtered rows? I would like to not overwrite the existing dataframe

Comment: just edited as you wished. Don't pass `inplace = True` and append the output to another list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the duplicate account number

```
 dtf[i].drop_duplicates(subset ="Account", 
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
```

or if you want to remove exact row duplicate:

```
 dtf[i].drop_duplicates(subset =[["Account","Verified","Paid"]], 
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
```

I hope it help

Comment: How could I create new dataframes with only filtered rows? I would like to not overwrite the existing dataframe

Comment: use : inplace=False and store it in a new varaible.

new_variable= dtf[i].drop_duplicates(subset =[["Account","Verified","Paid"]], 
                     keep = False, inplace = False)