# Keep duplicates rows in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

With following dataframes, how do I extract and keep in different dataframes:

- rows with unique `Account` only
- all rows with duplicated `Account`s

I have two datasets, `df[0]`...:

```
Account     Verified     Paid   Col1 Col2 Col3
1234        True        True     ...  ...  ...
1237        False       True    
1234        True        True
4211        True        True
1237        False       True
312         False       False
```

...and `df[1]`:

```
Account          Verified   Paid   Col1 Col2 Col3
41                True      True    ... ... ...
314               False     False
41                True      True
65                False     False
```

To pass through all dataframes in my list, without replacing my `df[i]`, and extract unique rows I used the following code:

```
filt = [] 
for i in range(0,1): 
    filt.append(df[i].groupby(list(df[i].Account)).agg('first').reset_index())
```

However, I would be also interested in passing through all dataframes in my list and, still not replacing my df, extract rows with duplicates. 
For example, in the example above, I should have a dataframe that includes accounts `1234` and `1237`, and a dataframe that includes only `41`.

How could I get these two datasets?

Comment: With [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) respectively, with option `keep=False` i.e. 'all duplicates'. See the 170 existing answers on [*\[pandas\] drop_duplicates duplicated*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+drop_duplicates+duplicated+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: I edited your title from *'save'* to *'keep'*, to help this get better answers and found more. We generally only use *'save'* to mean *'store to file'*, not *'keep the result of a calculation'*. Esp. when dealing with duplicates, the term is always *'keep'*

Comment: Also, it's not very pandas-idiom to have a list `df[i]` of multiple dataframes and iterate over it. Generally better to `merge` or `concat` the dataframes, and have one extra column to distinguish where they came from.

Comment: Thanks, smci. I will keep it on mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)** and **[`duplicated('Account', keep=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)** respectively.

You have two dataframes with some duplicates in the 'Account' column.
There's no need to write the line-by-line `groupby` hack you wrote.

**To get a dataframe with unique Accounts only i.e. duplicates dropped, use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)**. See its 
 `keep=‘first’/‘last’/False (i.e. drop all)` option, and `inplace=True` option.

```
>>> df[0].drop_duplicates('Account')    
   Account  Verified   Paid Col1 Col2 Col3
0     1234      True   True  ...  ...  ...
1     1237     False   True  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     4211      True   True  NaN  NaN  NaN
5      312     False  False  NaN  NaN  NaN

>>> df[1].drop_duplicates('Account')
   Account  Verified   Paid Col1 Col2 Col3
0       41      True   True  ...  ...  ...
1      314     False  False  NaN  NaN  NaN
3       65     False  False  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

and **to get a dataframe with duplicated records only, use [`.duplicated('Account', keep=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)** which means 'keep all duplicates'.

```
>>> df[0][ df[0].duplicated('Account', keep=False) ]
   Account  Verified  Paid Col1 Col2 Col3
0     1234      True  True  ...  ...  ...
1     1237     False  True  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     1234      True  True  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     1237     False  True  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>> df[1][ df[1].duplicated('Account', keep=False) ]
   Account  Verified  Paid Col1 Col2 Col3
0       41      True  True  ...  ...  ...
2       41      True  True  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

You might want to sort the last two dataframes in order of 'Account':

`df[0][ df[0].duplicated('Account', keep=False) ].sort_values('Account')`

**Note:** it's not very pandas-idiom to have a list `df[i]` of multiple dataframes and iterate over it. Generally better to merge or concat the dataframes, and have one extra column to distinguish where they came from. (Also more efficient, we only need to do `groupby`, `apply`, `drop_duplicates` etc. once)

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
filt = [] 
for i in range(0,1): 
    df=df[i]
    filt.append(df[df.iloc[::-1].duplicated('MAT')])
```